# How to modify the value of a variable?

Tags: java

```
public class SavingsAccount {
public static int annualInterestRate = 0;
private double savingsBalance = 0;

public double calculateMonthlyInterest(){
    return (savingsBalance * annualInterestRate)/12;
}

}
```

This is what I currently have. I did every part that was required except the set value. I need a static method to set value of annualInterestRate to something else. As you know, to modify something in static method, variable should be static as well. Thats why annualInterestRate is static. My problem is that I don't know how to create a method and don't hard code it. I need a method that can be tested in another class. Should I use set and get methods to execute what I want?

Comment: Do you know what `static` means or why do you add it everywhere? And googling for "setter method java" would be helpful.

Comment: Hint: `modifyInterestRate(int n)`

Comment: If this is a school assignment, I suggest you take some time to experiment and see for yourself what happens. You can re-assign a variable in Java by using VARIABLE = VALUE. Print a variable by System.out.println(VARIABLE)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `"but I am struggling"` - This is a good opportunity to practice some problem solving skills.  What *specifically* is preventing you from continuing?  Do you get an error?  Unexpected behavior?  What is failing and how does it fail?

Comment: I added static because I need static variables

Comment: @Alex: Not according to the description of the problem you don't.  The description implies that separate instances of `SavingsAccount` would have their own values.  `static` precludes that.  Why do you *think* you need `static` variables?

Answer (score 0):

The method method for accessing the member variable need to be declare as public，and member variable should be private such that it can be modified by the access method only.

Answer (score 0):

A `static` field would be a global variable, bound to the class. Occurring once.
So make the fields non-static and the field will be part of every SavingsAccount object, the `this`.

```
public class SavingsAccount {

    public int annualInterestRate = 0;

    public double savingsBalance = 0;

    public void calculateMonthlyInterest() {
        double y = (savingsBalance*annualInterestRate)/12;
        savingsBalance = y +savingsBalance;
    }

    public void modifyInterestRate(int n) {
        this.annualInterestRate = n; // Or simply:
        annualInterestRate = n;
    }
}
```

By the way **fields** need not be initialized. By default they will be 0, 0.0, null, false.

Answer (score 0):

Making those variable static means every instance of SavingsAccount sees the same values.

When you create my SavingsAccount, please set the value equal to Warren Buffet's balance, please.

A better idea would be to use instance variables:

```
public class Account {
    private double balance;

    public Account(double balance) { this.balance = balance; }

   public double getBalance() { return this.balance; }
   public void setBalance(double newBalance) { this.balance = newBalance; }
}
```